# Noob questions about UVs in Blender

Tags: uv

As I said in another question I made, I'm following a tutorial based on a book. I'm making this model called Captain Blender. But I stopped a long time ago and I'm just getting back to it and I was having some issues.

This time, the location of the UV islands is not matching the texture image file that's there. I don't know why this is happening and why I would leave it like that when I stopped. Makes no sense to me since I have older versions of the file where it's matching perfectly.

This texture was brought in from Zbrush. I simply painted on the model's head, exported that as a texture (seams were already made in Blender) and then brought back to Blender. I can't remember now if I had to adjust the islands. Is it matching perfect in the older files because I adjusted the islands to match the image, or is there a way in Zbrush to make sure they match the ones in Blender?

I don't remember doing anything on Zbrush before other than simply exporting the texture.

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Not my fault you didn't understand. Why would I delete YOUR edits? Put it back how it was. If no one answers then so be it. Your edit to my question is not correct. I know how to move the islands around. I'm asking if there's a way that no adjusting would be needed, as I don't remember doing it. I thought, in the past, the image brought from Zbrush fit perfectly without adjusting UV on Blender.

Comment: was the file you were working on, open and saved in a recent verseion of blender, before you did zbrush? and does it happen if you do a quick test on a new model?  It could be an update issue,(Cpt. B tut was originally for 2.48) or it could be an issue with zbrush/blender storing/restoring UV maps.

Comment: It's hard to say what was the reason behind the changing UV layout (that was you importing it from ZBrush to Blender, so you should've noticed if something was wrong) but it should be possible to repair easily. As you can notice, top islands are flipped with position (you can grab them into place), and bottom right ones are flipped with position and rotation (you can scale them by -1).

Comment: Yes, it was definitely an older version of Blender dval. But in an older file, they are perfectly positioned. I guess I must have moved them and don't remember. I must have unwrapped UVs again later, messing it up, and saved it that way. Good tip @Mr Zak, I actually rotated them by eye, I could have just flipped them. As for moving them with G, everyone just does it by eye correct? I'm just trying to make sure there isn't a more accurate way of doing it.